# Difference between std::exception and "..."

Tags: c++, exception

```
A:      catch(...)  
B:      catch(std::exception& e)
```

the question is what can A catch but B cannot.

And why in C++ an universal root exception that can catch anything is not introduced

--- added
I am sorry, I should have said that I understand in C++ you can thrown any type like int, but apart from this, what else can be thrown?

My problem is that I am trying to find what exception is thrown from code, which can be caught by A but not B. This exception is definitely not a type like "int". It must be a system exception or memory violation sort of thing. I am just wondering what that could be.

Comment: C++ doesn't have a 'root' exception type that all exceptions inherit from because C++ can throw anything, including types that cannot inherit; e.g. `int`. C++ can throw anything because they didn't see a reason to make exceptions less general. It's similar to C++ templates; C++ templates don't rely on inheritance and so are more general than, for example, Java or C# generics which do rely on inheritance.

Comment: Certain Windows SEH exceptions can sometimes be caught by `...` but not by `std::exception`.

Comment: @MooingDuck only if you compile with crazy flags, use the recommended /EHsc (if you can) and you'll be fine

Answer (score 30):

`catch (...)` is a so-called "catch all" block. It will catch *any* C++ exception.

`catch(std::exception& e)` will catch *only* exceptions that are derived from `std::exception`.

Here is an example of an exception that will be called by the catch-all, but not the second version:

```
throw 42;
```

This might seem odd to you, and it is.  The important thing to realize is that *anything* can be thrown as a C++ exception -- not just `exception`s or things derived from `exception`.  As @bames53 mentions in the comments, there is no root exception type that all exceptions are derived from, like there is in some other languages.

It is also important to note that a catch-all block is very easy to abuse.  In fact, as a general rule of thumb it might be best to assume that all catch-all blocks are program defects.  Of course, there is no "always" in programming, but this is a safe assumption to start with when you are learning to use exceptions.

The reason why catch-all blocks are Evil is because of how they are typically used.  Normally, a naive programmer will write a catch-all in an attempt to catch any programming error and then, critically, continue letting the program has run as if nothing has happened.  This is a disaster waiting to happen.  The program state is now indeterminate.  Something, somewhere has gone wrong.  You cannot safely ignore exceptions and keep going like everything is just fine.  Even if your program does continue to run, there might be a subtle heap corruption somewhere that will adulterate the program's computations or its outputs.  When heap corruptions do occur, the best thing that you as the programmer can hope for is an immediate crash.  That way you can get a call stack and a dump file at the point of corruption and find and fix the problem.  But when you have a catch-all in place, you have lost all the context where this corruption takes place.  It becomes nearly impossible to find the real defect in your code.

---

Of course, there are valid and valuable uses of a catch all handler.  One on the most common is to write a global exception handler which then re-`throw`s the exception.  This global handler could initiate some kind of fault logging, perhaps by either logging an error itself, or spawning an external program which does the logging outside of the failing program.  By re-throwing the exception, you give delegates an opportunity to handle the exceptions that can be handled, while allowing the exception which can't be handled to terminate the program.

Rethrowing an exception is simple to do.  Simply call `throw` with no argument, as with:

```
catch (...)
{
  // some magic
  throw;
}
```

---

Another thing to keep in mind is that when you do catch an exception, it is generally best to catch a `const` reference, rather than just a reference.

Comment: Also, some older versions of VC++ (and maybe even newer with certain settings) caught also SEH exceptions with `catch(...)`, which is definitely not a good idea (you may end up ignoring an access violation or a page guard exception used to expand the stack).

Comment: @MatteoItalia:  Are you sure about that?  It has been a long time since I've dealt with SEHs and you're probably right, but I don't remember that.

Comment: I'm not sure about the old default behavior, but you can certainly still change the settings to enable catching SEH exceptions.

Comment: @JohnDibling: IIRC it was in VC++ 2003 (7.1), I remember being bit by this stuff once.

Comment: @Damon: I agree and would add that `std::current_exception` is THE tool for such a handler…

Comment: @Damon:  I've tried to incorporate this idea in to my answer.

Comment: See my comment to the main question about catching SEHs, its not default anymore (and thankfully hasn't been for a while) but you can enable it if you're sufficiently crazy

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is anything without `std::exception` in its (public) inheritance heirarchy:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try
    {
        throw false;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught std::exception" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught something else" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Caught something else
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `int`s?

```
try {
    throw 123;
} catch (std::exception &e) {
    // this won't catch
} catch (...) {
    // this will catch
}
```